# Delegated access to shared mailboxes without rights to deleting messages

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, mailbox, delegation

So I'd like to grant my users access to a shared mailbox with delegated access - easy enough. (We use Office 365)

But how can I restrict that access, so they can't DELETE anything in that mailbox? I'd like them to still be able to move items, create new folders etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. If you want them to be able to move content, then they need to be able to delete content, because that is what a move is.

Permissions basically fall in to two groups - read only and full control. There is no middle ground.